# Delete an objectID from an array in Parse via Button

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have an application setup so that there is an array that contains objectId's that the current user is friends/connected with. I'm attempting to create a button that deletes a single `objectId` from that array (kind of like an unfriend button). I'm currently passing the `objectId` value from a query in one view controller to another view controller that actually contains the friends profile and the delete/unfriend button. I'm getting the actual `objectId` as a string in the friends profile and I can print the `objectId` but I can't seem to figure out a way to delete this single `objectId` from the array.

Using `PFUser.currentUser()?.removeObject()` gives me an invalid field name error.

Anyone have an insight for me? 
Let me know if there is more clarification needed! Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I have tried to also utilize this as my object code. userObjectId is received from another view controller and grabs the proper objectId of what I'd like to remove from the current users "accepted" array. This code gives me an error of "NSInternalInconsistencyException reason: Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object" I've tried to remove this objectId from the array in several different ways but can't seem to get it to stick. Thanks again.

```
var userObjectId = ""
var object: PFObject = PFObject(className: "User")
object["objectId"] = userObjectID
PFUser.currentUser()?.removeObjectsInArray([object], forKey: "accepted")
PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: Hint : Get PFObject with id -> Remove that PFObject

Answer (score 0):

```
    let object = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Your Class", objectId: "objectId from array")
    object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && success == true {
            //Delete the objectId from the array
        }
    }
```

This will also remove the object from any array that holds it.